# Have save_post write to database image meta

Tags: posts, metabox, save-post

Programming rookie back again.

I have been studying the `add_action('save_post','')` but I am having difficulty getting it to work for my needs. The concept is simple - update the database information for an attachment's meta info.

Here's where I'm at. I have my `add_meta_box` working great with an input box that is pre-populated with the Camera information from image meta.

If I make an edit in this Camera field and update the post, no matter what variation of `update_post_meta` I try, it's failing. For example:

```
$camera = $imgmeta['image_meta']['camera'];
$update = $_POST['exif_field_camera'];
update_post_meta($post_id, $camera, $update);
```

I am fearing a horrible rookie mistake here, since it's not working.

The code I am using to retrieve the information and using it as part of my `add_meta_box` is:

```
$args = get_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => null,
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $post->ID
) );
foreach ($args as $attachment) {

$imgID = $attachment->ID;
$imgmeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($imgID);
$camera = $imgmeta['image_meta']['camera'];
}
```

What would the code be to write the new Camera input box information?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `foreach`? You're setting those values a whole bunch of times, but not doing any output before you change them.

Comment: The foreach sets the values for the input box that's displayed in the add_meta_box. So if the values are changed, shouldn't the $POST_() pick that up? If so, then I am doing something wrong with the update_post_meta

Comment: So...there's more to the foreach than you posted here?

Comment: Yes, this was a snippet. I can paste the whole thing if you feel its relevant. The foreach does not exist in my update_post_meta save_post. As I mentioned, I am able to extract data fine, I can't save it.

Comment: Where are yuo setting `$post_id`? At this point, I see nothing inherently wrong with what you've got, so it may not be within the code you've posted.

Comment: I'm editing another plugin which is open source under the GNU general public license. I've scanned it to find where it is defining $post_id, and came up blank. That said, I've changed my update_post_meta to update_post_meta($post->ID, $camera, $update);, and it's still not saving the value in the input box when I change it and update my post.

Comment: You're sure that `$post->ID` has a value? Are you sure it's even making it through the filters and such that should be in place to get to `update_post_meta()`?

Comment: Pretty sure. I have global $post defined in the function, and If I do $postID = $post->ID | echo $postID, it shows the same post ID as in the URL.

Comment: Anything else come to mind?

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong with the code you posted so far as I can tell. Start doing `print_r()`s on everything and see what's falling apart.

Comment: Tried to print_r, but am not getting much since it's changing the page during the save/update. The debug info shows my $postID as the same as URL. Would it help if I shared the entire function?

Comment: After a bit of a break from working on this, I am realizing that the code is being saved in a NEW meta_key which is naming it the value of $camera, and the meta_value of $_POST. So you're right, this IS working after all, however not how I want it to. Is there a way to update attachment meta? I think that's what I'm after - not POST meta.

Comment: Could you please update your question with that info and clean up that comment mess (delete your own)? Thanks.